# How to track keywords that the user click on in flurry analytics?

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

How to track keywords that the user click on in flurry analytics ? and how/where to see such info ?

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "keywords". Are keywords logged as part of a user's interaction with the app?

Comment: @FlurryAnalyticsSupport no, keywords are attribution parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keywords are being added as parameters to a User Acquisition Analytics campaign link, it is not possible to view them in the Flurry portal.